# Can not open project with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project that was already working with IntelliJ IDEA but now,when I want to open it with IntelliJ IDEA, I am facing this error message:"Contains no IntelliJ IDE project".

Comment: What does the directory structure look like? Can you see for example a `.idea` folder, or some `pom.xml` or `.iml` files?

Comment: for me, restarting my system worked, same as the good old times! xD

Answer (score 23):

I faced the same issue. Deleting *.project* file in from the home directory and reopening **solved** the problem.

Comment: had it with intellj idea ultimate and deleting .idea/ folder fixed it.

Comment: deleting the `.project` file worked me me - thanks!

Comment: Had a .project file with git conflicts, fixing the conflicts in local editor made it possible to open the project again.

Answer (score 11):

In my case (**PyCharm**), there was one particular project that refused to open, while other projects worked perfectly. Deleting the `.idea` folder did not fix the issue. The fix that worked for me: `File > Invalidate Caches > (Select all) > Invalidate and Restart`. This will remove caches and indices for all projects, and new caches will be built on re-open.

Comment: Worked for me in IntelliJ Ultimate. I opened another working project, then "Invalidate  Caches...", checked "Clear file system cache and Local History", "Clear VCS log caches and indexes". After IDE restart I was able to open the faulty project again.

Answer (score 4):

Try importing project by selecting File -> Import Project... (as for IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4).

Does it help?

Comment: By this way i just open the project on IntelliJ IDEA.But the run icon is deactivate. and i cant run this project.

Comment: In my case, open Maven Projects window, right click on the project and choose Reimport on the context menu, everything is back to normal now.

Comment: I preferred the delete .project file solution as I open my repo in IntelliJ from the command line and it is easier for me to delete a folder and open the project instead of opening the IDE and looking at the project from there.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue, but I was not getting any error message. When I tried opening the git repository, nothing was happening in IntelliJ. For me using the following IntelliJ options helped:

Go to FILE menu -> New Project -> Project From Existing Sources.

Now select your project folder. Then I chose "Create project from existing sources" and went through the generator, basically just clicking Next.

Comment: This totally worked thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case invalidating caches helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this recently and by Jetbeans adding 
" -Dide.mac.file.chooser.native=false " to vmoptions would solve the problem.

But in my case, it did not work, I noticed the error log and it was not able to open due to no permission to read a file under.IDEA folder inside my project so went to system preferences and gave WebStrom permission to files and it started working.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1721?_ga=2.190528747.1517998312.1582653181-1398648508.1578306760

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had generated a apache camel project by running `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="org.apache.camel.archetypes" -DarchetypeArtifactId="camel-archetype-spring-boot" -DarchetypeVersion="3.4.0"` on my terminal but it did not generate a .idea folder and so InteliJ would not open it. So I copied the .idea folder of a similar project and edited the `modules.xml, workspace.xml, project template.xml and misc.xml` to match my project name and class path, then InteliJ opened the project with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, .idea folder (which configures the IDE settings) was missing. I have copied this folder from my existing and properly working projects and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I didn't invalidates caches. I just reload all gradle projects by clicking in in the "Reload all Gradle projects" in gradle view, after each project build/sync, they will be imported as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate cache and check all the cases should fix the probnlem.

[image]